# Make specified cell read only in Ken do Grid when authorization flag is No

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Ex code:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.col1).Width(120).ClientTemplate("..some events and function data values----");
columns.Bound(p => p.col2).Width(120);
columns.Bound(p => p.col3);
```

have to make `col1` as `read-only` when condition met

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hash syntax](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/faq#how-to-apply-conditional-logic-to-column-templates-for-server-bound-grids) to display the input (or whatever) if the condition is met and display a span if it is not:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.col1).Width(120)
       .ClientTemplate("# if (IsAuthorized) { #" +
                       "<input>...</input>" +
                       "# } else { #" +
                       "<span>Not Authorized</span>" +
                       "# } #");
```

In this example `IsAuthorized` would be a field from the model bound to the grid, but you could test a value passed into the view's model, a hidden, etc.

Comment: Thank you @Steve Greene